Can't autogenerate the weights for a perticular pallet for benchmarking
After successfully releasing the substrate app using
cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks

I tried following command:
./target/release/node-template benchmark pallet --chain dev --pallet pallet-project-tips --extrinsic * --steps=50 --repeat=20 --execution=wasm --wasm-execution=compiled --output custom-pallets/project-tips/src/weights.rs --template ./.maintain/frame-weight-template.hbs

It gives error don't know why:
error: unexpected argument 'Cargo.toml' found

Usage: node-template benchmark pallet [OPTIONS]

For more information, try '--help'.

Also, where can I find the maintain/frame-weight-template.hbs template.

Following command works
cargo run --release --features runtime-benchmarks -- benchmark pallet \
    --chain dev \
    --wasm-execution compiled \
    --pallet "pallet-template" \
    --extrinsic "*" \
    --steps 50 \
    --repeat 20 \
    --output pallets/template/src/weights.rs --template=./.maintain/frame-weight-template.hbs 

--extrinsic "*" is the point
Template is in maintain folder
